# Analytics term for turning row values into column names and count its assigned values

Tags: terminology, data-wrangling, aggregation

Do we have a data mining/analysis term for [turning row values into column names and count its assigned values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058219/r-turn-row-values-into-column-names-and-count-its-assigned-values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation.
See  [Aggregate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)

Comment: The linked question does indeed involve aggregating counts by date, but, it also involves pivoting the resulting rows to column values.

Comment: Correct, I referred only to the counting part. The full computation can be also done using aggregation and transposing.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the part about counting values, that is indeed simply a form of "aggregation". Just call it counting even.

If you mean the part where the resulting row values become columns in the result table, then I'd say this is called "pivoting", made famous by Excel's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table though this comes up in RDBMSes in general.